# I am trying to setup gitlab cicd for webdriverio headless firefox but getting error

Tags: gitlab, cicd, webdriver-io, firefox-headless

I am trying to setup gitlab cicd for firefox but getting error 'ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255'
This is my gitlab yml contains:

```
stages:
  - test

webdriverio_chrome:
  stage: test
  image: atools/firefox-headless:java11-node16-latest # Specify the image for the job
  
  before_script:
    - echo "Installing dependencies..."
    - npm install
    - npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev

  script:    
    - npm run wdio

  after_script:
    - npm run generatereport

  artifacts:
    name: chromeReport
    paths:
      - allure-report/*
      - allure-results/*
```

This is what I am getting when running the pipeline in gitlab:

[pipeline error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWYIO.png)

I have tried npm install geckodriver as well but still it is not working.

Comment: Please post all code, including errors as code - not images. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for explanation.